# PostgreSQL - How to split a cell content after a sub-string (a specific word) into a new column

Tags: postgresql

I currently have a PostgreSQL database which contains two specific strings: Unique Word and Unique Word 2.  I want to split Column A cells after the Unique Word 2, including the Unique Word, and Data 2 that follows it into a new column (Column B) in the same row.

What would be the SQL query to accomplish that?  There are over 50k rows like this.

**Column A** (the following data is all in 1 cell as a string)

Unique Word:

- Data
- Data

Unique Word 2:

- Data 2
- Data 2

Comment: Assuming your table also has a(n auto incremented) primary key, you could use that to split it by a unique word.  Such as `select * from tablename where idcolumn < (select idcolumn from tablename where columnA = 'Unique Word 2');`

Comment: It is auto incremented with an ID column.  I don't quite see where it splits the cell into two pieces and puts it into a new column cell?  Since Column A Unique Word .. Data ... Unique Word 2 ... Data are all part of a single cell / string.

Answer (score 0):

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=7fe2f931f661cb0ac58968a20c832672)

Assuming these data could represent your cases:

```
'UNIQUE_WORD_1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit UNIQUE_WORD_2 amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr',
'UNIQUE_WORD_1 sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut UNIQUE_WORD_2 labore et dolore magna',
'UNIQUE_WORD_1 aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. UNIQUE_WORD_2 aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos'
```

This query splits the text at the second unique word into two parts. The second part is everything behind the second unique word, the first is everything before. From the first part, the first unique word can be deleted (replace with empty string):

```
SELECT
    replace(text_parts[1], 'UNIQUE_WORD_1', '') as first_part,
    text_parts[2] as second_part
FROM (
    SELECT 
        regexp_split_to_array(texts, 'UNIQUE_WORD_2') as text_parts 
    FROM test_data) s
```

Result:

```
first_part                                   second_part
-----------------------------------------    ---------------------------------------------
Lorem ipsum dolor sit                        amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut    labore et dolore magna
aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.            aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
```